# AWX Upgrade Help - 6.0.0 to 8.0.0

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I have been running AWX from the https://github.com/ansible/awx repo for a while now.  It is currently version 6.0.0 and I have been attempting to upgrade to version 8.0.0.  I wanted to add SSL during this upgrade but neglected to notice that the SSL port was in use.  However, even after making the changes in the installer/inventory file back to the original port, the web and task containers are still being started on port 443.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?  I've deleted the images, volumes, repo, and updated the docker-compose.yml file where I am saving the configuration and database data.  Still now luck.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you ran the install.yml playbook after changing the port in installer/inventory. From the installer directory run: `ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml`

That will update your docker-compose.yml file accordingly and start the containers. After confirming that the awx_web container is now listening on port 80 (or whatever port you're changing it back to), I would shut the containers down and bring them back up normally to confirm everything will work as intended after e.g. a host reboot:

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose pull && docker-compose up --force-recreate -d
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I've learned a lot about the way the software is configured since my post.  I'll try this and let you know the result.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'll try this the next time I update and let you know the outcome.